Mismatch between impulse response gotten from differentiation of unit step response vs solving directly with input $\delta(t)$ for operator $ 2D + 1 $
To find the unit step for the operator $ 2D + 1 $, where $ D $ is the differential operator, we proceed as follows:
Unit Step Response
The unit step function $ u(t) $ is defined as:
$$ u(t) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if } t < 0 \\
1 & \text{if } t \geq 0 
\end{cases} $$
We need to find the response $ y(t) $ of the system $ 2D + 1 $ to the input $ u(t) $. This involves solving the differential equation:
$$ (2D + 1)y(t) = u(t) $$
Rewriting $ 2D + 1 $ in terms of the differential operator:
$$ 2 \frac{dy(t)}{dt} + y(t) = u(t) $$
Solving the Differential Equation
First, we solve the homogeneous equation:
$$ 2 \frac{dy(t)}{dt} + y(t) = 0 $$
The characteristic equation is:
$$ 2r + 1 = 0 $$
$$ r = -\frac{1}{2} $$
So, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$ y_h(t) = C e^{-\frac{t}{2}} $$
Now, we need a particular solution $ y_p(t) $ for the non-homogeneous equation. Since the input $ u(t) $ is a constant (1 for $ t \geq 0 $), we assume a constant particular solution:
$$ y_p(t) = A $$
Substitute $ y_p(t) = A $ into the differential equation:
$$ 2 \frac{dA}{dt} + A = 1 $$
$$ 0 + A = 1 $$
$$ A = 1 $$
So, the particular solution is $ y_p(t) = 1 $.
The complete solution is:
$$ y(t) = y_h(t) + y_p(t) = C e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1 $$
To find the constant $ C $, we apply the initial condition. For the unit step response, we usually assume the system starts from rest, which means $ y(0) = 0 $:
$$ y(0) = C e^{0} + 1 = 0 $$
$$ C + 1 = 0 $$
$$ C = -1 $$
Therefore, the unit step response is:
$$ y(t) = (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1 ) u(t) $$
Unit Impulse Response
The unit impulse function $ \delta(t) $ is the derivative of the unit step function:
$$ \delta(t) = \frac{d u(t)}{dt} $$
So we can find the unit impulse response by differentiating the unit step response, we proceed as follows:
From the unit step response, we have:
$$ y(t) = (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1)u(t) $$
To find the unit impulse response $ h(t) $, we differentiate $ y(t) $ with respect to $ t $:
$$ h(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1)u(t) \right] $$
Using the product rule for differentiation, we get:
$$ h(t) = \left[ \frac{d}{dt} (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1) \right] u(t) + (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1) \frac{d}{dt} (u(t)) $$
First, differentiate $ -e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1 $:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1) = \frac{d}{dt} (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}) + \frac{d}{dt} (1) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 0 = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} $$
Next, we use the fact that the derivative of the unit step function $ u(t) $ is the Dirac delta function $ \delta(t) $:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (u(t)) = \delta(t) $$
Now, combine these results:
$$ h(t) = \left( \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \right) u(t) + (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1) \delta(t) $$
For $ t \geq 0 $, $ u(t) = 1 $, so:
$$ h(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + (-e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + 1) \delta(t) $$
Therefore, the unit impulse response is:
$$ h(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} + (1 - e^{-\frac{t}{2}}) \delta(t) $$
But if you solve the ODE $ (2D + 1)h(t) = \delta(t) $ directly without differentiating the solution for unit step response we get: $$ h(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} $$
So is the relation $ \delta(t) = \frac{d u(t)}{dt} $ not valid here?

The Dirac delta function, $\delta(t)$ has the following key property:
Sifting Property: The Dirac delta function "picks out" the value of another function at a specific point.
$$
   \delta(t - t_0) f(t) = \delta(t - t_0)f(t_0)
   $$
This property is often referred to as the "sifting" or "sampling" property.
Using this we see above that $$ (1 - e^{-\frac{t}{2}}) \delta(t) = (1 - e^{-\frac{0}{2}}) \delta(t) $$
$$ = 0 $$
So $h(t)$ simplifies to $$ h(t) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{t}{2}} $$

You should have included these extra steps by editing your original post.

Mathematics are not broken and the unit impulse function is still the derivative of the unit step function. You made several mistakes along the resolution, hence the final mismatch. Let's take another look at some steps.
Since the initial differential equation $2\dot{y} + y = u$ is linear and inhomogeneous, its solution is indeed made of the general solution to the associated homogeneous problem, namely $y_h(t) = Ce^{-t/2}$, and a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation, denoted here by $y_p(t)$. However, the constant ansatz $y_p(t) = A$ you used doesn't work, because $2\dot{y}_p(t) + y_p(t) = A \neq u(t)$, when $t < 0$.
Instead, we may observe the method of variation of the parameter by setting $y_p(t) = c(t)e^{-t/2}$, which leads to the relation $\dot{c}(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{t/2}u(t)$ after being plugged into the original differential equation. The latter relation is then integrated as follows :
$$
c(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int e^{t/2}u(t) \,\mathrm{d}t 
     = \frac{1}{2}u(t) \int_0^t e^{\tau/2} \,\mathrm{d}\tau 
     = (e^{t/2}-1)u(t)
$$
In consequence, one has $y_p(t) = c(t)e^{-t/2} = (1-e^{-t/2})u(t)$ and finally $y(t) = y_h(t) + y_p(t) =$ $Ce^{-t/2} + (1-e^{-t/2})u(t)$, with $C = 0$ due to the initial condition $y(0) = 0$. So, you ended with the right solution "by chance", because your first error (i.e. the constant particular solution) was somehow compensated by attaching artificially the unit step function at the end $-$ and which you didn't justify by the way.
Next, you tried to recover the relation $\dot{u} = \delta$ by differentiating $y(t)$. Nevertheless, it cannot work, because the original differential equation imposes $u = 2\dot{y} + y \neq y$. Actually, you should have had instead : $\dot{u} = 2\ddot{y} + \dot{y} = \delta$, given that
$$
\dot{y}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left((1-e^{-t/2})u(t)\right) 
           = \frac{1}{2}e^{-t/2}u(t) + (1-e^{-t/2})\delta(t) 
           = \frac{1}{2}e^{-t/2}u(t)
$$
and
$$
\ddot{y}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{-t/2}u(t)\right) 
            = -\frac{1}{4}e^{-t/2}u(t) + \frac{1}{2}e^{-t/2}\delta(t) 
            = -\frac{1}{4}e^{-t/2}u(t) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(t),
$$
where we used the identities $(1-e^{-t/2})\delta(t) \equiv 0$ and $e^{-t/2}\delta(t) \equiv \delta(t)$, coming themselves from the relation $t\delta(t) \equiv 0$ together with the Taylor expansion of the exponential function.
